# Best way to store and use data in Angular that updates periodically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to create an app that pulls data from a dynamically generated JSON file every 5 minutes and updates the view with the new data.  The JSON file contains all the data for the website, which is data for a slider and for a list of events.  I've read that global data can be stored in the $rootScope, or retrieved and served using a .service or .factory.  I've tried different ways with no success and I'm lost.  What is the best way to periodically pull data from an api for the entire app, store it, and use it?

Currently I have this code:

```
app.factory("Poller", function Poller($http, $timeout){
    var data = {'slider' : [], 'activities' : []};
    var getData = function(){
        $http.get('http://example.com/json.php')
            .then(function(r){
                data = r.data;
            });
        $timeout(getData, 1000*60*5);
    }
    getData();

    return{
        data: data
    }
});

app.controller('ListController', function(Poller){
    this.activities = Poller.data.activities;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

See **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHKQv8tG7Cp5aYDklNG0?p=preview)**

```
app.factory("Poller", function Poller($http, $interval){
    var data = {
        'newData': {
            'one' : '',
            'key' : ''
        },
        'fetchCount': 0
    };

    var getData = function() {
        data.fetchCount += 1;
        $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two')
            .then(function(response){
                data.newData = response.data;
            });
    };

    var loopGetData = function() {
        $interval(getData, 5000);
    };

    loopGetData();

    return{
        data: data,
    };
});

app.controller('ListController', function($scope, Poller){
    $scope.activities = {'one' : '', 'key' : ''};

    $scope.Initialize = function () {
        $scope.$watch(function () { return Poller.data.newData; },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                $scope.activities = newValue;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.Initialize();
});

app.controller('CountController', function($scope, Poller){
    $scope.fetchCount = 0;

    $scope.Initialize = function () {
        $scope.$watch(function () { return Poller.data.fetchCount; },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                $scope.fetchCount = newValue;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.Initialize();
});
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that the json file hold data for other controllers.  I want to make one http call in the service rather than multiple http calls through the controllers.

Comment: just updated my answer. now the service will just fetch the new data every interval and the controllers will update the specific values they're listening to.

Comment: This is great!  I have one issue though.  In the ListController, if I use `$scope.activities = newValue`, the view never gets updated.  However, if I set `var list = this` ... `list.activities = newValue` it does work. Any ideas?  Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: i'm not too sure i understand what your code looks like enough to debug it. could you post your updated code? one thing i see is that you have to define your list as `$scope.list`. then you can do `$scope.list.activities = newValue;`. if your variable is not on the `$scope` object angular won't know to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here looks like you have defined the function `getData()` inside the `Poller` factory that makes the ajax request, but didn't bind that to a key inside the factory's returning object.

Try adding this,

```
return{
    data: data,
    getData: getData
}
```

And then remove the `getData()` you have right before the returning block.

Now I feel like depending on your app's setup, if you want to achieve long polling effects, you should attach `getData()` to a variable in some top-level controller that is always present so that you can invoke the `getData()` periodically using `$timeout`.

Speaking of `$timeout` is that you should extract the `$timeout` outside of the `getData()` and so that the function itself simply makes the ajax request. More modular, single responsibility design that way, which makes that factory function more usable in other areas of your app if you ever need.

If you want to update the information after you finish the ajax requests every five minutes, you should looking into `$broadcast` and `$rootScope`, you can basically tell your entire Angular app that some rootScope variable or service has changed, and they will update accordingly. You need some kind of callback set up after the ajax request inside whichever controller you are invoking the `getData()` function.